# How to overwrite previous TextView and EditText in android

Tags: java, android, xml, spinner

I have a spinner with the `values = {4,5,6,7}` , initially spinner selected value is set to `4` , therefore 4 `TextViews` and 4 `EditTexts` showing in the activity.

Now I want if the user select value `5` from the spinner then these previous 4 `TextViews` and `EditTexts` will overwrite with new 5 `TextViews` and 5 `EditTexts`.
How can I do so ? any help?

Comment: How did you did that for 4 textviews ?

Comment: remove all textview and edittext then add programmatically again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can manage through loop like...

```
for( int i = 0; i < spinner.getSelectedItem(); i++)
{
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText(textArray[i]);
linearLayout.addView(textView);
}
```

For create view one after another create programmatically layout like this:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
setContentView(linearLayout);
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL)
```

Like this you can manage programmatically as per your need.

Comment: successfully implemented, thanks, now can you also help me in getting back EditText values which user will input.

Comment: u can store it in array and get back as per position

Answer (score 0):

1. You can write your TextView and EditText as an item of RecyclerView and every time you can have as much items as you want. 
   OR
2. every time add TextView and EditText programmatically from the java code.